# In Fabric, how to access the name of the requested task?

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I have a Fabric script with many tasks.  I'd like to add a simple "yes/no" confirmation at the very beginning that includes the hosts to be run on and the task requested.

```
hosts = env.hosts
task_name = ?
if not confirm('Run "%s" on %s?' % (task_name, hosts)):
    abort('Aborting per user request.')
```

So, when I run `fab -H user@1.2.3.4 deploy`, the confirmation will be `Run "deploy" on user@1.2.3.4?`

Unlike the well-documented `env.hosts`, I cannot find an `env.task_name` variable to achieve this.